# Windows 7 with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I am using Windows 7. Is it possible to use two operating system on the same laptop? If yes please provide instruction to do that.

Comment: Two ? A friend of mine has 6 in his laptop :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the [Windows Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/windows-intaller), called Wubi. It is a nice way to dual-boot and it's easy to use. Install it on to your computer, then follow the nice and easy steps, then when you boot, there you go! It's there, on a selection screen.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Just follow the installation instructions and when "where do you want to install ubuntu" pops up, select "next to windows 7" or if you have free space in your HD, select it. Free space > make partition ext4 /// remember to give at least 1gb for the swap partition.